# How to return the column heading for multiple matches, from multiple criteria, in Excel?

Tags: arrays, excel, multiple-matches

I'm working with 40+ price lists for different groups of customers. By entering the item number and price, I'd like to show the names of all the price lists that match that item/price. I've set up the items and pricing lists like the table below. Some items have the same prices in multiple price lists, and some price lists do not list all items.

```
Item     ListPrice  Red    Blue   Green    Grey
Hosaka2  $200       $180   $188            $171
TrodesH  $460       $410   $380   $400     $380
TrodesL  $810       $680   $680   $720
Shuri    $80        $72           $72      $70
```

I'd like to enter TrodesH and $380 into cells and have the formula return Blue & Grey. Or enter Hosaka2 and $200 and have the formula return ListPrice.

I've used this [Index array formula](http://eimagine.com/how-to-return-multiple-match-values-in-excel-using-index-match-or-vlookup/) in the past to return multiple matches to a single entry. To, for example, list all the account numbers whose address matches the zip code I enter. It's very handy. But here I'm looking for the combination of item and price. Any ideas how I might move forward?

Edit: For better legibility in the Excel file, I've placed the above data in a worksheet named "Matrix" and the lookup formulas in a worksheet named "Check."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that A1:F5 contains the data, and H2 contains the item of interest, such as TrodesH, and I2 contains the price of interest, such as $380, try...

```
J2:

=COUNTIF(INDEX($B$2:$F$5,MATCH($H2,$A$2:$A$5,0),0),$I2)

K2, confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER, and copied across:

=IF(COLUMNS($K2:K2)<=$J2,INDEX($B$1:$F$1,SMALL(IF(INDEX($B$2:$F$5,MATCH($H2,$A$2:$A$5,0),0)=$I2,COLUMN($B$1:$F$1)-COLUMN($B$1)+1),COLUMNS($K2:K2))),"")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: As I noted in the edit above, I moved your J/K formulas to a different worksheet to make the results easier to read, and it works great.

I tested it with numbers from several orders. One order had several items that, together, matched prices from 7 different price lists. But only one price list matched the prices for all the products I entered. 

It would certainly be possible to have an order that matched more than one price list, but I'm using this to direct my next action, not as a final answer. For that, it works great. Thanks, Domenic!

Answer (score 1):

Taking the diagram below as a model (adjust it to your own data layout and places), you can enter this formula at `J1` and copy/paste into the colored area:

```
J1:
=IFERROR(INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($B$2:$F$5)
  /($A$2:$A$5=$H1)/($B$2:$F$5=$I1),COLUMN(A:A))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Note, though, with this method, the array formula is calculated for each of the columns/price list, whether there's a match or not.  Whereas with my method, the array formula is only calculated for the columns that have a match.  So if there are only two columns that have a match, the formula only gets calculated twice, not 5 times as in this example or 40+ times as specified..  With 40+ columns, there could be a performance issue, although not necessarily significant.

Comment: @Domenic I don't believe there are serious performance concerns. Tests are ok for 42 columns and 1000+ rows, needs more benchmarking. The important things are the formula is not volatile and does not require any helper column. It's pretty simple as well, which I always favor for reasonable datasets unless performance becomes a significant issue.

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned, while there could be a performance issue, it may not necessarily be significant.  Of course it would depend on the actual size of the data.  Even so, I know that there are those who are willing to sacrifice some efficiency in order to avoid helper columns.  :-)

Comment: Your solution works very well also. I'm working with 80+ price lists but only 200 rows. There may be a performance difference, but with this small of a data set I really can't detect it.

Comment: I've copied these formulas down 20 rows in my Check worksheet. Using Domenic's formulas, if there's no product/price to look up, the formulas result in #N/A. Using A.S.H.'s formulas, if there's no product/price, the result is "Price List" in every cell. Of the two, I'd rather have #N/A. I'll keep testing with both solutions, though.